# How to use a node module in Angular which is not created for Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, require

Example module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/qrcode

It's easy for me to use it in pure javascript:

```
var QRCode = require('qrcode')

QRCode.toDataURL('I am a pony!', function (err, url) {
  console.log(url)
})
```

But I can't use "require" in Angular, right?
Anguar has this:

```
import { X } from Y
```

How can I use the qrcode reader in Angular? What would the X and the Y be in this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install install package, along with the types for full functionality in a typescript environment such as Angular:

`npm install --save qrcode && npm install --save-dev @types/qrcode`

Then in your component you can now `import * as QRCode from 'qrcode'` and use it in your typescript environment.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly it depends on the package. But for most something like this will work.

```js
import * as QRCode from 'qrcode'
// Or
import QRCode from 'qrcode'
```

Alternatively if you have packaged the library using Angular CLI you can force typescript to ignore the use of packages it doesn't have typings for by doing:

```js
delcare var QRCode: any;
```